# Kinnim mix-ups with different numbers of pairs in each group

Tags: korban, birds, tractate-kinnim

In certain cases, the Torah prescribes the bringing of a pair of birds as an offering, one as a *chatat* and the other as an *olah*. See [Lev 12:8](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0312.htm), [Lev 14:22](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0314.htm), [Lev 15:14](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0315.htm), [Lev 15:29](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0315.htm), and [Num 6:10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0406.htm).

The governing principle of mix-ups of birds is that we do not allow birds to be offered (a priori) if there is a possibility that we might accidentally offer both birds of a pair as *olot* or both as *chataot*, and if a group of X pairs is entirely mixed with a group of Y pairs, then we can bring min{X, Y} pairs from the X+Y birds. See [Kinnim 1:3 (1:4)](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h5b.htm).

---

The mishna [Kinnim 2:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h5b.htm) describes what happens if two sets of four birds get mixed up (translation edited from [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Kinnim.2.2?lang=bi)):

> שתי נשים, לזו שתי קינים ולזו שתי קינים--פרח מזו לזו, פוסל אחד בהליכתו; חזר, פוסל אחד בחזירתו.  פרח וחזר, פרח וחזר--לא הפסיד כלום:  שאפילו הן מעורבות, אין פחות משתיים.
>
> If there are two women, this one has two pairs and this one has two pairs and one bird flew from this woman's [pair] to the other woman's [pair], it invalidates one bird by its leaving. If it then returned [to its original pair] it invalidates one by returning. If it flew back and forth multiple times it does not cause further invalidation since even if they are mixed up, there are at least two [valid] birds remaining.

Birds are flying back and forth (one at a time) between the two groups of four, ending with four and four. The mishna allows each owner to offer two of the birds in front of them. I glean from this mishna that the minimum number of pairs we are able to offer in this case (even after much mix-up) is equal to the the number we could offer if all birds were mixed into one group.

The next mishna ([2:3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h5b.htm)) speaks of owners each with different numbers of birds (translation edited from [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Kinnim.2.3?lang=bi)):

> לזו אחת, ולזו שתיים, ולזו שלוש, ולזו ארבע, ולזו חמש, ולזו שש, ולזו שבע--פרח מן הראשונה לשנייה, לשלישית, לרביעית, לחמישית, לשישית, לשביעית, וחזר--פוסל אחד בהליכתו, ואחד בחזירתו:  הראשונה והשנייה, אין להן כלום; השלישית, יש לה אחת; הרביעית, יש לה שתיים; החמישית, יש לה שלוש; השישית, יש לה ארבע; והשביעית, יש לה שש.  פרח וחזר--פוסל אחד בהליכתו, ואחד בחזירתו:  השלישית והרביעית, אין להן כלום; החמישית, יש לה אחת; והשישית, יש לה שתיים; השביעית, יש לה חמש.  פרח וחזר--פוסל אחד בהליכתו, ואחד בחזירתו:  החמישית והשישית, אין להן כלום; והשביעית, יש לה ארבע.  ויש אומרין, השביעית לא הפסידה כלום.  ואם פרח מבין המתות לכולם, הרי כולם ימותו.
>
> If this one has one [pair of birds], and this one has two [pairs of birds], this one has three [pairs], this one has four [pairs], this one five [pairs], this one six [pairs] and this one seven [pairs], and one bird flew from the first [group] to the second [group] and one [from the second] into the third, and one [from the third] into the fourth, and one [from the fourth] into the fifth, and one [from the fifth] into the sixth, and one [from the sixth] into the seventh, and then one returned [to its previous group], it invalidates one pair [for each] when it leaves and one pair [for each] upon its return. The first and second [groups] have no valid birds left, the third has one [valid pair], the fourth has two, the fifth has three, the sixth has four, and the seventh has six. If it [= a bird] flew back and forth [again], it invalidates one set when it leaves and one set upon its return. The third and fourth [group] have nothing, the fifth has one [valid pair], the sixth has two and the seventh has five. If a bird flew back and forth [again], it invalidates one pair when it leaves and one upon its return. The fifth and sixth [groups] have no valid birds and the seventh [group] has four... If a bird that is left to die flew into their group they all must be left to die.

More simply (as far as I can tell), say we have two groups, where group A has two birds (= one pair) and group B has four birds (= two pairs), and a bird flies from A to B and then a bird flies from B to A. For this case, based on this this mishna, no bird that is currently in group A can be brought, and one pair from those currently in group B can be brought. If another bird then flies from A to B, then no bird can be brought (by the last clause of the mishna). From here we see that there is a case where we bring *no* birds, instead of the one pair we would be allowed to bring if all six birds were mixed together.

How do I resolve this contradiction? Am I incorrectly inferring rules from the specific cases? Do Kinnim 2:2–3 not hold by Kinnim 1:3?

Answer (score 3):

My (un-sourced) understanding is that the difference is that the end of Kinnim 2:3 is dealing with a case where an entire group of birds can no longer be offered. This means that they attain the status of *chata'ot hametot*, and then if one of them flies into any other group of birds the entire group becomes invalid. (See the last two comments of Yachin on Kinnim 2:3, who I think also makes this point.)

To consider the simplified case you constructed, after the first two flights, the whole of Group A become *chata'ot hametot*, since none of them can be brought. That is why if one of them were to fly into Group B it would invalidate the entire group.

This is different to the case in Kinnim 1:3 where no group is ever given the status of *chata'ot hametot* before they all get mixed together.

Comment: This is an appealing approach. Perhaps you want to include in this answer why a bird's disqualification is necessarily permanent. It would seem to be a disqualification based on doubt/fear of offering incorrectly, but the fear is obviated (in a certain sense) if they are all mixed together.